# How can I "uncrush" PNG's from extracted ipa packages on windows? [pngcrush]

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipa, pngcrush

I've been trying to uncrush PNG's extracted from an ipa for a while and can't seem to be able to get anything to work.

I don't own any Apple devices (except for an iPod Touch, a gift from a friend) but I want/need an app that has only been released for the iPad, I have extracted the contents of the ipa but I can't find a way to uncrush the PNG's.

Is there any way that I can do this on Windows?

I can actually use a Mac app because I have a running Hackintosh, but, it is running an older version of OS X (at least older than 10.6 but I can't check cause it crashes).

Example of crushed PNG: http://www.mediafire.com/?pe43no79aj8agsy

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out this blog post http://blog.egopoly.com/2011/05/03/how-to-uncrush-pngcrushed-images-from-an-iphone-app-bundle/

Answer (score 2):

Details on the format and a command line to "uncrush" a modified PNG is here:

[iPhone Dev Wiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format)

Comment: @A.M.K : Then try the command line utility on your hackintosh. The command line utility is written by Apple and should just work. There also appear to be some online "uncrushers"

Comment: I would need the SDK but I can't install it because it is an older version of OS X, I wanted to try to find another solution before either making a new hackintosh or trying some other 4gb+ SDK dmg's.

Answer (score 0):

Since I wrote the blog post referenced in the comment on the question, I'll just post the answer here (for a Mac):

It was (in 2012)

% mkdir uncrushed
% /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -dir uncrushed
-revert-iphone-optimizations -q *.png

Since Developer files have been moved around since, pngcrush is now located at:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush